# Set DataContext in XAML Rather Than in Code Behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've read in other posts that in place of specifying the DataContext in code behind it can be specified in XAML.

I have an ObservableCollection declared and populated in the constructor of my main class where I also set the DataContext:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace ItemsControlDemo
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Person> PersonList { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            PersonList = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

            PersonList.Add(new Person(16, "Abraham", "Lincoln"));
            PersonList.Add(new Person(32, "Franklin", "Roosevelt"));
            PersonList.Add(new Person(35, "John", "Kennedy"));
            PersonList.Add(new Person(2, "John", "Adams"));
            PersonList.Add(new Person(1, "George", "Washington"));
            PersonList.Add(new Person(7, "Andrew", "Jackson"));

            DataContext = this;
        }

        private void Button_Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            PersonList.Add(new Person(3, "Thomas", "Jefferson"));
        }

        private void Button_Remove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            PersonList.Remove(TheDataGrid.SelectedItem as Person);
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public Person() { }

        public Person(int id, string firstName, string lastName)
        {
            ID = id;
            FirstName = firstName;
            LastName = lastName;
        }

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

If I do this, all works well in my application.

However, if I remove "DataContext = this;" from the constructor and instead set the DataContext in the Window element of my application

```
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

I get no data.

This is the XAML where I set the DataContext after I have removed it from code behind:

```
<Window x:Class="ItemsControlDemo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ItemsControlDemo"
        Title="Items Control Demo" Height="350" Width="400"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" Name="TheDataGrid" SelectedValuePath="ID"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  AlternatingRowBackground="Bisque"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding PersonList}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID"         Binding="{Binding Path=ID}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding Path=FirstName}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name"  Binding="{Binding Path=LastName}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <Button Content="Add Item"    Margin="5" Click="Button_Add_Click"/>
            <Button Content="Remove Item" Margin="5" Click="Button_Remove_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Any help in what I am doing incorrectly would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Any reason you need to do this since you aren't following MVVM by putting a load of code in the code-behind file?

Comment: @Charleh:  I know that I can do it in code behind but this is a sample application I am using to learn more about using a DataGrid with binding.  As such, I am exploring all possible ways of doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to setup your source **before** calling InitializeComponent

Edit: Actually you just need to instantiate it before InitializeComponent, since it's an ObservableCollection it implements INotifyCollectionChanged, so if you modify the collection, your grid will be updated with the changes.

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        PersonList = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        InitializeComponent();
        PersonList.Add(new Person(16, "Abraham", "Lincoln"));
        PersonList.Add(new Person(32, "Franklin", "Roosevelt"));
        PersonList.Add(new Person(35, "John", "Kennedy"));
        PersonList.Add(new Person(2, "John", "Adams"));
        PersonList.Add(new Person(1, "George", "Washington"));
        PersonList.Add(new Person(7, "Andrew", "Jackson"));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you!  I didn't realize that I was initializing before populating my data source.  Your prompt answer is much appreciated!

Comment: @PeterBuilt Also, your Person class needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: Since I'm using an ObservableCollection for my list of Person objects I do not need to explicitly implement NotifyPropertyChange.  I believe that is the advantage for using ObservableCollection.

Comment: @PeterBuilt Well ObservableCollection notifies changes in your collection, but not changes in your individual items, see this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291339/if-observablecollection-is-used-do-i-still-need-to-implement-inotifypropertycha)

Comment: Interesting.  I wasn't aware of that distinction.  Thank you for bringing it to my attentions.

Answer (score 2):

216's answer works. Alternatively, you can implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` so the XAML is notified when you do set `PersonList`.

`ObservableCollection` only notifies when **items in the collection** change. If you want to notify when you **assign a new value** to the collection (e.g. `PersonList = new ObservableCollection<Person>()`), you need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private ObservableCollection<Person> personList;

    public ObservableCollection<Person> PersonList
    {
        get { return personList; }
        set
        {
            if (value == personList)
                return;
            personList = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("PersonList"));
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        PersonList = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

        // etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing an alternative solution.