# Listbox is not Populating using binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, listbox

I am trying to convert my existing program in c# wpf, using mvvm pattern.

The first part is select the Folder location of the files to be process and populate the listbox

I found an example here using Mvvm Light: [WPF OpenFileDialog with the MVVM pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619505/wpf-openfiledialog-with-the-mvvm-pattern)

the example in the link above is selecting a Folder.

this is the structure of my project
[image]

this is the code of my FileListView.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="MvvmLight1.Views.FilesListView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MvvmLight1.Views"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" Width="730.029">

    <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding FileNames}" Margin="5,5,5,5"/>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

this is my list which reside in ViewModel\OpenFileDialogVM.cs

```
public System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<string> FileNames { get; }
    = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<string>();
```

this is my code for populating the list. but it doesn't work

```
var files = System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(SelectedPath, "*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);

            FileNames.Clear();

            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                FileNames.Add(file);
                Console.WriteLine(file);
            }
```

What is wrong with my code above?

---

Code Update:

On my folder structure I have ViewModel Folder and inside it I have OpenFileDialogVm.css[image]

but why is it that the IDE only recognize the ViewModelLocator.

I even Build the project.

I even set the DataContext in the CodeBehind of FileListView user control but still it doesn't populate the listbox

```
public partial class FilesListView : UserControl
    {
        public FilesListView()
        {
            DataContext = new OpenFileDialogVM();
            InitializeComponent();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Where do you set the DataContext for the FilesListView?

Comment: What does not work? Does the files variable not get populated or ListBox doesn't get populated?

Comment: @Rekshino i didn't set it. Where do i need to set it?. And i didn't even know that i need to set it.  Thank you

Comment: @sachin the variable is populated. i write the file names in the console using the for loop and its working

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606803/silverlight-setting-datacontext-in-xaml-rather-than-in-constructor

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26206612/set-datacontext-in-xaml-rather-than-in-code-behind?rq=1

Comment: Nice question to RelativeSource bindings: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84278/how-do-i-use-wpf-bindings-with-relativesource?rq=1

Comment: You need to learn how the DataContext works in WPF.  It flows through the visual tree (which is why you NEVER want to bind DataContext to the visual tree itself `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}`) from the root (typically the Window).  But if it isn't set, your bindings won't work because there's nothing to bind against.  You can use a tool like Snoop to examine the DataContext and your bindings at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add it to your UserControl:

```
<UserControl
.....
xmlns:viemodels="clr-namespace:MvvmLight1.ViewModels"
/>
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <viemodels:OpenFileDialogVM/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
....
</UserControl>
```

Comment: i tried your code but it doesn't work. the IDE doesn't recognize the viemodels:OpenFileDialogVM. i even set the data content in my code behind. but still it doesn't populate the listbox. thank you

Comment: I don't know exactly what is the Name of your ViewModel class and what namespace it is into. The class must have public modifier and your ViewModel project must be referenced in View project.