# observable collection and inotifypropertychanged

Tags: wpf

An ObservableCollection is self-contained when it comes to raising the CollectionChanged event because it implements INotifyPropertyChanged and INotifyCollectionChanged. So i think , we don't need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged again.

but i have seen some example where folks are defining ObservableCollection as property and raising property changed event in setter. i don't understand why this is done again or in better words why they are Raising property changed event in setter(see below code). As we already know that ObservableCollection automatically raises when add,update is done, then we need not to raise again.right?

please clarify my doubt.

```
public class TheViewModel()
{
   private ObservableCollection<Camper> _campers;
   public ObservableCollection<Camper> Campers
   {
       get { return _campers; }
       set
       {
           if (Equals(_campers, value)) return;

           _campers = value;
           RaisePropertyChanged("Campers"); //Or however you implement it
       }
   }
```

Comment: A new Campers is not the same as adding to or removing from an existing campers.  Campers.Add calls get not set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set Campers to point to a new instance, that RaisePropertyChanged will do the job for you. Otherwise you will have a reference to the old instance and the View will remain out of sync. The other solution to this is, every time you set Campers to point to a new collection, set again the ItemsSource for your DataGrid or ListView or whatever control you use.

Indeed this works as long as you Add or Remove items from your collection. To conclude, that's the difference, when you set again

```
Campers = new ObservableCollection<Camper>();
```

your RaisePropertyChanged will be triggered.

**Code update:**

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="ObservablePropertyChanged.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding items}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <Button Content="Change collection" Click="btnChangeCollection_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> items { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        items = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        items.Add("One");
        items.Add("Two");
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private void btnChangeCollection_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        items = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        items.Add("Three");
        items.Add("Four");
    }
}
```

As i don't have INPC interface implemented and no PropertyChanged added on the set of the items collection, after clicking the Button you will not get the View updated with items "Three" and "Four".

And here is another way to accomplish this behavior:

```
    public ObservableCollection<string> items
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<string>)GetValue(itemsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(itemsProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for items.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty itemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("items", typeof(ObservableCollection<string>), typeof(MainWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
```

Using this dependency property, the ListView will remain in sync.

Comment: i have bind Campers in my view and once i add item to campers, its updates the view using below code.

Notice: i have removed RaisePropertyChanged("Campers")

public class TheViewModel()
{
   private ObservableCollection<Camper> _campers;
   public ObservableCollection<Camper> Campers
   {
        get;
        set;
   }

so my question is if observable collection is automatically updating view then we dont need to use RaisePropertyChanged.

Comment: @shashank Without that RaisePropertyChanged, if you change the collection which Campers points to, you will be out of sync.

Comment: @shashank there are two different things. Adding and Removing items or changing the entire collection on which Capmers points to. So, without the call to RaisePropertyChanged try Camper = new ObservableCollection<Camper>() from somewhere and start adding items. Your view will not be updated.

Comment: i tried as you said and it worked. perfect. thanks . To conclude it

1. if whole property is replaced with new value then INotifyPropertyChanged comes into picture and we need to raise event in setter. for example Campers  is replaced with new instance of  ObservableCollection. Also, this applies to any property of any datatype like int , string etc.  but on the other side

2. in case of observable collection, if you are just adding, removing items in same instance (and of course not replacing with new instance) then you dont need to Raise event in setter.Right?

continued---

Comment: continued--
Now when i try to update 'Name' property of Camper class using --
Campers[0].NAME = "Foo";
Campers[0].NAME = "Goo";

it is not updating my view using both 1 and 2. why?

Comment: @shashank Camper class needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface and set RaisePropertyChanged on its properties.

Comment: perfect. I got my concepts clear. 
thanks a lot.
but a new doubt is that how are you doing this with dependency property?
probably this requires another discussion. i dont know if admin will allow. but if you can give little idea about it that will be very useful because your way of explaining  is awesome. or share me some resources (which is specific to this doubt only)